# objective-c : When you click on the first cell, an issue occurs in which the last cell is selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Currently, a total of three cells are created. Strangely, when you click on the first cell, the last cell is clicked.

To check the log In this section

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I checked the cell I clicked by writing the log as below.

```
NSIndexPath *c = [_tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
NSLog(@"LOG 3 : %@", c);
```

First cell click :

```
LOG 3 : <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}
```

second cell click :

```
LOG 3 : <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000200016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}
```

When the third cell is clicked:

```
LOG 3 : <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000400016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 2}
```

I have confirmed that this is the log.

Although it looks normal,
Actually the simulator confirms that if you click cell 0, the third cell is selected and the third cell is changed to light gray background.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I think the process of creating a cell in this part is wrong.

Currently I am creating a cell as shown below.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    TableViewCell *cell;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < fileCount; i++) {
        indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        cell.fileName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_fileList[i] valueForKey:@"name"]];
        cell.fileDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_fileList[i] valueForKey:@"date"]];
        cell.fileSize.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_fileList[i] valueForKey:@"size"]];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

The reason I do this is because the _fileList Array contains several Dictionary with name, date, size pairs
So we were creating a cell using the for statement.

For some reason, when you click on the first cell, will the last cell be a click?

Comment: Please learn to understand how a table view data source works. `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called multiple times –  for each row separately passing the actual index path. And don't use `valueForKey` to get a value for a key in a dictionary unless you can explain why you explicitly need KVC.

Comment: Its not your responsibility to create all the cell in one `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. This delegate method will be called each time for each `indexpath`. your responsibility is just to deque the cell and customize it according to `indexpath` and then return. nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I think I need to study a lot about UITableView.

Answer (score 0):

Should adopt the **UITableViewDataSource** and **UITableViewDelegate** protocols and *ViewController.h* should look as shown below.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,
UITableViewDelegate>
```

then

```
#pragma mark - TableView DataSource
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _fileList.count;
}
```

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"TableViewCell";
    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:
        UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.fileName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_fileList[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
    cell.fileDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_fileList[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"date"];
    cell.fileSize.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_fileList[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"size"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It has helped a lot.

Comment: In UICollectionView, does not it matter if I do not have the same code (cell == nil)?
I am currently using this only.

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"GridViewCell";
GridViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    
cell.deviceName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_deviceList[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"]];
cell.hostName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_deviceList[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"hostname"]];

return cell;